# Convert a background of a canvas in System.Drawing.Bitmap?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, canvas, kinect

How to convert a background of a `CANVAS` in `System.Drawing.Bitmap`? The `canvas` image is the background from the kinect image. The application is made in WPF.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have created a rectangle on the canvas and saving it may be you can change the code accordingly for your usability

```
using (Graphics g = Graphics.FromImage(image))
{
    g.CompositingMode = System.Drawing.Drawing2D.CompositingMode.SourceCopy;

    foreach (var child in canvas.Children)
    {
        if (child is System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle)
        {
            var oldRect = child as System.Windows.Shapes.Rectangle;

            // need to do something here to make the new rect bigger as the scale is clearly different
            var rect = new Rectangle((int)Canvas.GetLeft(oldRect), (int)Canvas.GetTop(oldRect), (int)oldRect.Width, (int)oldRect.Height);
            g.FillRectangle(Brushes.Black, rect);
        }
    }
    RenderTargetBitmap bmp = new RenderTargetBitmap((int)Canvas1.Width, (int)Canvas1.Height, 96, 96, PixelFormats.Default);
    bmp.Render(Canvas1);
}
```